# Solution verification for a Bernoulli trial problem

Tags: probability

We are performing a series of Bernoulli trials (with probability $p$ for success) until we obtain $r$ successes. What is the probability of requiring exactly $n$ trials ($r\leq n$)?

In other words, we are looking for the probability of $r-1$ successes in $n-1$ trials and success at the $n^{\text{th}}$ trial. Since these two events are independent from one another, we can calculate the probability of both and multiply them.

The probability of $r-1$ successes in $n-1$ trials is ${n-1 \choose r-1} p^{r-1}(1-p)^{n-r}$.

The probability of success at the $n^{\text{th}}$ trial is $p$.

So the answer is ${n-1 \choose r-1} p^{r}(1-p)^{n-r}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is just a single instance of a negative binomial pdf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Alternative_formulations

Comment: Ok thank you. Also, can we solve/view this problem as a conditional probability? Given $r$ successes, $n$ trials...